# How do I get the image to appear in my HTML5 code

Tags: html

I am having issues when I upload my code to the server.  I need to have an image of a camel on the right but for some reason the image will not appear.  I have tried the example code and when that is used the image will appear but not with my code. I am putting my code below so any help would be wonderful.  Also this is my first try at this language so I am extremely new to all of this.

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>

<!-- Fig. 2.18 Solution -->
<! __ Includes camel image -->

<html>
       <head>
          <meta charset = "utf-8">
              <title> Homework 1- 2.18 Solution </title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <table border = "1"   width = "640" >
             <tr>
                <td><h1> Objectives </h1>
                   <ul>
                      <li>  To be able to create tables with rows and
                            columns of data. </li>
                      <li>  To be able to control the display and formatting of tables. </li>
                      <li>   To be able to create and use forms. </li>
                   </ul>
                   <em> Yea, from the table of my memory I'll wipe away all 
                        trivial fond records. </em><br  />
                        William Shakespeare.
                   </td>
                   <td><imag src="camel.png"  alt= "Camel picture"
                         height = "310"    width = "200"  />
                </td>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: It's `img` not `imag` - e.g. `<img src="camel.png" alt="" />`

Comment: Homework? If so please edit your post to include the homework tag.

Comment: Where's the "too localized" option in the Close dialog?

Comment: @MarkKram There's no such thing as a `homework` tag.

Comment: You're also missing a DOCTYPE, and what is with the random spacing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<img src="camel.png"  alt= "Camel picture"
                         height = "310"    width = "200"  />` - take the 'a' out of 'imag'.

Comment: Thank you after looking at this for over six hours today I just did not see the 'a'.  Thank you for pointing it out in such a kind way.